# Covert Python Http request to Java

Tags: java, rest, http, oauth

I want to convert following Python code snippet of Http request to equivalent Java code,

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from numpy import array
try:
    from commands import getoutput # python 2
except ImportError:
    from subprocess import getoutput # python 3


SELDON_API_IP="35.192.98.23"

def get_token():
    payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
    response = requests.post(
                "http://{}:8080/oauth/token".format(SELDON_API_IP),
                auth=HTTPBasicAuth('oauth-key', 'oauth-secret'),
                data=payload)
    token =  response.json()["access_token"]
    return token

def rest_request():
    token = get_token()
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
    payload = {'meta':{},'data':{'ndarray':[[101]]}}
    response = requests.post(
                "http://{}:8080/api/v0.1/predictions".format(SELDON_API_IP),
                headers=headers,
                json=payload)
    print(response.text)

rest_request()
```

I tried converting `get_token()` part using unirest Java

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://35.192.98.23:8080/oauth/token")
                  .header("content-type", "application/json")
                  .body("{\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\",\"username\": \"oauth-key\",\"password\": \"oauth-secret\"}")
                  .asString();
```

But in this Java code I am getting error "Full Authentication Required". How can I convert this complete Python snippet to Java code(with or without unirest, anything is fine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username and password are not supposed to be part of the JSON body. It is not in the Python code. The username and password are part of the `auth` parameter. What this does is create an `Authorization` header. Based on this `HTTPBasicAuth`, it seems that [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is used. What this means is that the value of the `Authorization` header should be  "Basic base64(username:password)"`, where` base64`is a generic function that will base 64 encode the string`":"`, the username and password, delimited with a colon.

With Java 8, you can use the [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class to encode the value. So you would do

```
String credentials = "ouath-key:oauth-secret";
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeAsString(credentials.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://35.192.98.23:8080/oauth/token")
                  .header("content-type", "application/json")
                  .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64)
                  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to encode your auth parameter  ('oauth-key', 'oauth-secret') in base 64. Just like you did in python.

I don't know what oauth server you are using but i am pretty sure it returns Json so you might have to change your HttpResonse generics to `HttpResponse<JsonNode>`.